# Can every for/while loop be replaced with forEach, map, reduce, filter?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, functional-programming

To me, it seems that whatever logic I would write in a for/while loop could be placed in the callback passed to map, reduce, filter. I'm sure you might have to modify the code some but in theory I can't image a situation where you're forced to use a for/while loop.

Can anyone provide examples where its required to use a for/while loop?

Comment: It's not - as you say, it's true that you can use the native array iteration methods everywhere instead.

Comment: sometimes you only want to iterate the array less than n times (n= size of the array), depends on the nature of the data and what you are trying to do with the data

Comment: When iterating over a small enough collection, it is much more computationally efficient to use a for loop than to use the FP equivalents due to the overhead involved with setting up the stream for the FP loops.

Comment: @Andonaeus native JavaScript doesn't have streams - I'm guessing you're thinking about Java

Comment: @AnthonyC well, you still CAN do that without using a loop. You generate an array which contains the numbers [0, 1, 2...n] (where **n** < than your other array length). You then do something like `arr.forEach(i => otherArr[i])`. That's not really more efficient, though, and it's pretty much uglier than using a loop. I wouldn't even suggest doing that IRL - just using it as an example that technically, you could avoid a loop.

Comment: How would you do an infinite loop (e.g. a game loop) without using recursion or while?

Comment: @naomik You are correct, I misread the question :)

Comment: In particular reduce can replace all loops, as it can summarize the values using another array. But the semantics of filter and map are worth it. Note that it can also be more verbose than a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the statement were false, no functional programming language could exist. In other words: all imperative solutions can be rewritten as declarative ones. However, there might be implementation details that can be imperative (hah) to your particular use case. For example, breaking nested loops based on complex conditions is something that is typically easier to implement in an imperative form.